# Plugin on CRM 2016 throwing strange Exception

Tags: c#, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2011, microsoft-dynamics

I have a plugin which works fine on test system but on production it is throwing an strange exception. The plugin is registered on pre and post event of contact creation.

Below is the exception

```
Unhandled Exception: System.ServiceModel.FaultException`1[[Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.OrganizationServiceFault, Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35]]: System.BadImageFormatException: Microsoft Dynamics CRM has experienced an error. Reference number for administrators or support: #1C99C823Detail: 
<OrganizationServiceFault xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/xrm/2011/Contracts">
 <ActivityId>607632be-97ab-4704-961c-7f552681a51e</ActivityId>
 <ErrorCode>-2147220970</ErrorCode>
 <ErrorDetails xmlns:d2p1="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/System.Collections.Generic" />
 <Message>System.BadImageFormatException: Microsoft Dynamics CRM has experienced an error. Reference number for administrators or support: #1C99C823</Message>
 <Timestamp>2017-12-05T14:44:03.5336134Z</Timestamp>
 <ExceptionRetriable>true</ExceptionRetriable>
 <ExceptionSource>PluginExecution</ExceptionSource>
 <InnerFault>
 <ActivityId>607632be-97ab-4704-961c-7f552681a51e</ActivityId>
 <ErrorCode>-2147220970</ErrorCode>
 <ErrorDetails xmlns:d3p1="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/System.Collections.Generic" />
 <Message>System.BadImageFormatException: Microsoft Dynamics CRM has experienced an error. Reference number for administrators or support: #6482593B</Message>
 <Timestamp>2017-12-05T14:44:03.5336134Z</Timestamp>
 <ExceptionRetriable>false</ExceptionRetriable>
 <ExceptionSource i:nil="true" />
 <InnerFault i:nil="true" />
 <OriginalException i:nil="true" />
 <TraceText i:nil="true" />
 </InnerFault>
 <OriginalException>System.BadImageFormatException
```

Comment: This might help... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36069766/system-badimageformatexception-when-plugin-executes

Comment: try clean build and re-registering your plugin...

Answer (score 0):

As you can see the exception is a BadimageFormatException which could be several things: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k7137bfe.aspx

You might get better details if you turn on plugin tracing and view the Plugin Trace Logs inside Dynamics CRM. Here is a good article: https://www.powerobjects.com/2016/07/05/debugging-your-plug-ins-with-the-plug-in-trace-log/

You can add trace statements into  your code.  My guess is the assembly's target needs to change.